# How hot does it have to get for hiking to become unsafe?

Tags: hiking, temperature

In June, Seattle had a major heatwave with temperatures reaching 41C with 30-40% humidity. It was a bit cooler in the mountains but still quite unpleasant during the day. This made me wonder - at which temperature is it no longer safe to go hiking? Now, I do understand that this varies based on cloudiness, weight in your backpack, what clothes you're wearing, how much wind is blowing, etc, but I presume someone like the US military would have a nice chart going into detail on this topic, due to numerous military campaigns in desert areas.

I did try to search "temperature limit for hiking" but all the search results were opinion based rather than linking to solid scientific research.

Comment: humidity is a factor.

Comment: Take a look at this.  Gives data on Army training in the heat. https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/military-s-climate-change-problem-blistering-heat-killing-soldiers-during-n1032546

Comment: Quoted temperatures are usually shade temperatures, and there's not a lot of shade in the desert.  But there's also not a lot of humidity

Answer (score 15):

The limit isn't temperature, it's [heat index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index).  Since your body cools itself by sweating, you need to take the humidity into account when figuring out if you're going to overheat.  As an example, 10% humidity and 41°C (what you might find at Arches National Park) will heat you about the same as 100% humidity and 28°C (which you might find in the Everglades), both of which have a heat index of 38°C (100°F).

The absolute limit for a human is a heat index of around 54°C (130°F): above this point, you risk heat injury just lying around in the shade.  For most people, the practical limit is somewhere between 30°C and 40°C (85°F and 105°F), depending on personal fitness and heat adaptation.  But variation outside this range is possible: I once encountered someone suffering from heat exhaustion at a heat index of just 26°C (79°F).

Comment: You deserve the green check for this complete answer!

Comment: do you find heat index more or less useful than wet bulb temperature?

Comment: @njzk2, I find heat index more useful, because it's what the local weather reports and forecasts use.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not just about the temperature, it’s also about the level of difficulty ( easy, moderate, strenuous, etc.), distance , elevation, humidity and how hydrated the hiker is.  From personal experience a 1 mile hike with 99 Fahrenheit , around 10% humidity while staying hydrated is doable. Not comfortable but doable.

Comment: A hike of a mile isn't enough time or (in walkable terrain at least) exertion  to risk your internal temperature rising. And that's really low humidity so sweating cools you efficiently. In a similar vein I've been trekking in the desert a bit warmer than that, for several full days, but also low humidity. That was easy compared to slightly cooler but with much higher humidity